# On the domain restriction of a floor step function expressed as a piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So I was doing some exercises on piecewise functions, and came across a problem that says:

> Sketch the graph of
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> \lfloor-x\rfloor, &-1\leq x\leq1\\
> x^2-4x, &otherwise
> \end{cases}
> $$

But I didn't really want to sketch the given function, as I am only looking through problem sets to sort of review or exercise myself. Instead of sketching the graph of $f(x)$, I intended to express the floor step function as a piecewise function also.

---

Here's my attempt:

So if we have a floor step function $$g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor,$$ then we can write it as a piecewise function
$$g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor=\begin{cases}
\;\;\vdots&\qquad\;\;\vdots\\
-1, &-1\leq x\lt0\\
\;0, &\;\,0\leq x\lt1\\
\;1, &\;\,1\leq x\lt2\\
\;2, &\;\,2\leq x\lt3\\
\;\;\vdots&\qquad\;\;\vdots
\end{cases}.$$ Then for each "piece", we can have a general statement that
$$g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor=n, \;for\;n\leq x\lt n+1, \;where \;n\in\Bbb Z.$$

Keeping this in mind, working on the floor step function $\lfloor-x\rfloor$, then I will get
$$\begin{align*} \lfloor-x\rfloor&=n, \;for\;n\leq-x\lt n+1\\ &=n, \;for\;-n\geq x\gt-n-1\end{align*}$$
Taking into consideration the restriction on the domain of $\lfloor-x\rfloor$, such that $x\in[-1,1]$, as provided in the original piecewise function $f$, I now have
$$\lfloor-x\rfloor=\begin{cases}
-1, &if\;\; 0\lt x\leq 1\\
0, &if\; -1\lt x\leq 0\\
1, &if\; -2\lt x\leq-1
\end{cases}$$
But clearly, the last "piece" of $\lfloor-x\rfloor$ as a piecewise function which states $\lfloor-x\rfloor=1, if -2\lt x\leq-1$, is a contradiction because of the aforementioned domain restriction that $x\in[-1,1]$.

---

So if I re-write $f$ as a piecewise function such that $\lfloor-x\rfloor$ is also expressed as a piecewise function, I am assuming that I have to write it as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, &if\;\; 0\lt x\leq 1\\
0, &if\; -1\lt x\leq 0\\
1, &if\;\; x=-1\\
x^2-4x, &if\;\; x\lt-1\lor x\gt 1
\end{cases}
$$
Am I doing this correctly?

I apologize if this may seem such an easy-to-answer question for some—if not most—of you here, but I just really need confirmation if I'm on the right track. Thank you!

Comment: It seems fine to me! You indeed get three parts where it takes different values in the interval $[-1,1]$. Sometimes a sketch might help you, at least on figuring out how to divide the domain.